# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, inner-join

I get this erro when trying to execute a DAO method on my Java code saying that theres is an error in my sql sintax. When I do it manually on MySQL nothing goes wrong apparently.

Error:

```
Informações:   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as p inner join usuario as u on p.usuario = u.idusuario where p.idprestador=2' at line 1
```

DAO Method:

```
public Prestador listarPrestadorDetalhe(int idprestador) {
    try {

        Connection conexao = Conexao.getConexao();

        PreparedStatement pstmt = conexao.prepareStatement("select p.telefone, p.celular, u.email"
                + "from prestador as p inner join usuario as u on p.usuario = u.idusuario where p.idprestador=?");

        Prestador prestador = new Prestador();

        pstmt.setInt(1, idprestador);

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            prestador.usuario = new Usuario();

            prestador.setIdprestador(rs.getInt("idprestador"));
            prestador.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));
            prestador.setCelular(rs.getString("celular"));
            prestador.usuario.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));

        }

        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();

        return prestador;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } catch (SQLException sql) {
        System.out.println(sql);
    }
    return null;


}
```

SQL script

```
select p.telefone, p.celular, u.email
from prestador as p inner join usuario as u on p.usuario = u.idusuario 
  where p.idprestador=2
```

Comment: I think you need a space between `u.email` and `from`

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you were to output the string created, you have the following statement:

```
select p.telefone, p.celular, u.emailfrom prestador as p inner join usuario as u on p.usuario = u.idusuario where p.idprestador=?
--                                  ^^^^^
```

I think you can see the problem.

Comment: I couldn't see the problem. My teacher told me that it might be something related to the mysql jdbc version.

Answer (score 0):

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conexao.prepareStatement("select p.telefone, p.celular, u.email"
                + " from prestador as p inner join usuario as u on p.usuario = u.idusuario where p.idprestador=?");
```

This should fix the issue.

The sql produced by your code is

```
select p.telefone, p.celular, u.emailfrom prestador as p inner join usuario as u on p.usuario = u.idusuario where p.idprestador=?
```

You need a space before the `from` clause.

Comment: Can you explain what you changed? This doesn't really help anyone understand what happened.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Please read the edit.